# How to make the canvas fit the screen

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am drawing a canvas in my app but the problem is that the canvas is not of the same size what the screen is. Mostly the canvas is covering only bottom right part of the screen. Whant can be done to make it fit to the screen.?

Here is the screen shot of how its appearing:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class AnimationView extends View 
{

    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart;
    private static final boolean DECODE_STREAM = true;
    private static byte[] streamToBytes(InputStream is) {
      ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int len;
      try {
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
          os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
      }
      return os.toByteArray();
    }

     public AnimationView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs) 
     {

      super(context,attrs);
      setFocusable(true);
      java.io.InputStream is;
      is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.flag);
      if (DECODE_STREAM) {
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
      } else {
        byte[] array = streamToBytes(is);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
      if (mMovieStart == 0) { // first time
        mMovieStart = now;
      }
      if (mMovie != null) {
        int dur = mMovie.duration();
        if (dur == 0) {
          dur = 3000;
        }
        int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % dur);
       Log.d("", "real time :: " +relTime);
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);

        int width = this.getWidth()/2; 
        int height = this.getHeight()/2; 

        mMovie.draw(canvas, width, height);
        invalidate();
      }


    }
  }
```

Here is XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#074068"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <com.androidqa.AnimationView
        android:id="@+id/View"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#074068" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change your xml to `android:height="match_parent"`

Comment: No.. Thats not helping. It remains same.

Comment: My guess is that your canvas IS the height of the screen. but what you are drawing on the canvas, is not. Check your layout designer, it will show the area its using..

Comment: You are right. The canvas is proper, but the image is not of that size, how to make the image cover the whole canvas.? Independent of the image size.?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Movie` is a custom class? I cant see what is in `Movie.draw()`

```
    int width = this.getWidth()/2; 
    int height = this.getHeight()/2; 

    mMovie.draw(canvas, width, height); // this method
```

But I can see you are offsetting the image for no reason. Aka, starting to draw at the center. Where the image itself is not centered at this point.

Inside your draw method, where you draw the image, scale the image before drawing. And draw this instead, at the origion.

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

But pass in the actual height of the view to your draw method:

```
    int width = this.getWidth(); 
    int height = this.getHeight(); 
    mMovie.draw(canvas, width, height);
```

Comment: Movie is not a custom class. You can see the whole project [here](http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-animated-gif-example.html). Now how to draw a image which fits the canvas in this project.?

Comment: @AkshatJaiswal Unfortunately, looking at the API, i see no way to scale the image. It seems like a limitation of the Movie class. I could be wrong, but i have no experience with it to know.